# Handling Time zone in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, timezone

What i need to achieve is , 
Show an UI with a combobox (containing all time zones) , and a checkbox below the combo box.
The check box should be shown only when the Timezone (selected combo box item) supports daylight saving time. Also check/uncheck the checkbox based on the last configuration when the UI control is rendered.

Now TimeZoneInfo class in C# allows me to get the list of timezones (data for Combobox).
But SupportsDayLightSaving property in TimeZoneInfo class indicates true when Checkbox is checked and false when there is **no check box or Checkbox is unchecked.**

So how do i determine via C# that  ,

1.Whether the timezone supports DayLightSavingTime (for eg: Indian standard time doesnt support DST) 
2.Whether DST is enabled or not (checkbox is checked/unchecked) if the timezone supports DST.

**EDIT**:
If i haven't explained properly before , here is the more detail info.
What i want to do :

1. Show/Hide checkbox (what is the if condition to take this decision)
2. If Checkbox is shown , Check/Uncheck the checkbox (what is the if condition to take this decision).

PS: According to MSDN SupportsDaylightSavingTime property , the value will be true if the checkbox is checked and false if the check box is unchecked or the timezone doesn't support DST. WIth this property and if the value is false then i cant determine whether to hide the checkbox or show it and uncheck the checkbox.
For eg: For Indian standard time i shouldn't show the checkbox , for this if i have to rely on the property value then i would get it as false and i can hide it.
But consider we have Berlin timezone (+1 UTC) with checkbox unchecked using control panel settings then i would retrieve the property value as false and applying the above logic will hide the checkbox but instead here i wanted to show the checkbox with the state unchecked.

**Edit with Answer**:
Looks like i couldn't explain the problem properly , I am sorry for that.
After a long googling and search i could see that .NET doesn't provide API to support my need. Hence came with a solution that ,

Check whether SupportsDaylightSavingsTime property is true , 
if then Show the checkbox with state checked. If the above property value is false , then check DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled value in the registry (HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation) . Because false here doesn't mean that the timezone doesn't support the DST instead it can also be disabled. If the value is 1 ,then show the checkbox with state unchecked (because it supports DST but its disabled at the moment) . If the value is 0 , then do not show the checkbox.(as the timezone doesn't support DST).

```
    //get the time zone info for the currently selected time zone.
        if (timeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingsTime)
        {
            //Show the checkbox.
            //Mark the checkbox state as checked.
        }
        else
        {
            //doesnt mean that the timezone doesnt support DST.
            int regValue;//Get the reg value of DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled  in 
            //location HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\

            if(regValue == 0)
            {
                //Donot show the checkbox.
            }
            if(regValue == 1)
            {
                //show the checkbox.
                //Mark the checkbox state as unchecked.
            }

        }
```

Comment: You are using Windows-Form, WPF, ASP.NET?

Comment: Its a wpf application . But doesnt matter because i explained the UI only for the understanding . My doubt is what is the API which i need to use to check my two conditions . 1. Show/Hide checkbox . 2. Check/uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's missing from your explanation, but I think I can infer from comments is that you are talking specifically about this checkbox:

[image: Time Zone Setting]

That only comes into play when you are using `TimeZoneInfo.Local`.  In other words, I can always do this:

```
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
Debug.WriteLine(tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
```

And regardless of whether or not that checkbox is set, `tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime` will return true, because the data for that zone supports it.

But using

```
var tzi = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
Debug.WriteLine(tzi.SupportsDaylightSavingTime);
```

The result could be false if the box was not checked, even if the zone data supports it.  This is discussed [in the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.local.aspx), and also [in this excellent article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free.aspx).

If I understand you correctly, you wish to specifically know whether or not the "Automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time" has been cleared, so that you can build a UI that mimics the one in Windows?

As you pointed out in one of your edits, you can get this from the registry if you like, but you need to check two different keys, not just one.  Per [the article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free.aspx):

> Depending on the version of Windows being used, this checkbox will set either the "DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet" or the "DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled" registry key values to one (1):
>
> ```
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
>     "DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled"=dword:00000001`
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation
>     "DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet"=dword:00000001
> ```

**However**, there's a much easier way to detect this condition:

```
static bool LocalDstDisabled()
{
    TimeZoneInfo localZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
    TimeZoneInfo realZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(localZone.Id);

    return realZone.SupportsDaylightSavingTime &&
           !localZone.SupportsDaylightSavingTime;
}
```

Comment: Also, in the future you might consider omitting the parts about your own local UI, since I don't think you really were asking for help about how to display a checkbox.  The narrower the scope of your question, the more likely you are to get relevant answers.

Comment: Matt, I'm so confused after his last comment that I give up this q now I think :)

Comment: Oh Matt :) Finally this is the answer i have been looking for . May be i could have better explained it from the beginning , sorry for not putting it in a right way . Nevertheless , you pointed out the right answer. Thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Whether the timezone supports DayLightSavingTime (for eg: Indian standard time doesnt support DST)

Use the [`TimeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.supportsdaylightsavingtime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property to test it.

**For Example:**

```
ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> zones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
foreach(TimeZoneInfo zone in zones)
{
   if (! zone.SupportsDaylightSavingTime)
      Console.WriteLine(zone.DisplayName);
}
```

> 2.Whether DST is enabled or not (checkbox is checked/unchecked) if the timezone supports DST.

I assume you are using Windows-Form application with a `ListBox` control for your GUI, in that case, hook up to the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event of your `ListBox` and make your DayLightSupport test just there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer . But yes i could find that SupportDaylightSavingTime can be used to determine whether a TimeZone supports DST or not. But this is not always true. Because for eg: if we uncheck the check box of Berlin timezone (+1 UTC , which supports DST) from Control panel settings and if we write a code to get the SupportDayLightSavingTime value for this time zone then we will get a value false (as per MSDN documentation) but if you see this timezone supports dst.

Comment: To be more clear , i want to first show or hide the checkbox (based on whether it supports dst or not) second the checkbox should be checked or unchecked (based on the previous configuration) , so what would be the two conditions (i.e if checks which i would need to use). If you see clearly i have two conditions but .NET offers me only one check SupportsDaylightSavingTime so what could be the other check ?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code will help, it's all code behind and simple things though.

**Updated after comments.**

some xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TimeZoneDaylightTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox Height="200" Name="TimeZonesListBox" SelectionChanged="TimeZonesListBox_OnSelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
            <CheckBox Height="30" Name="SupportsDaylightCheckBox">Supports DayLightSaving</CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TimeZonesListBox.ItemsSource = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones();
    }

    private void TimeZonesListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tz = TimeZonesListBox.SelectedItem as TimeZoneInfo;
        if (tz != null)
            SupportsDaylightCheckBox.Visibility = tz.SupportsDaylightSavingTime ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are almost near . In the selection changed , what i would like to achive is , either hide or show the check box , how can i do this . Ok , this how can i means , what would be the condition that i will use to determine whether to show or hide the checkbox ?

Comment: ahh, hold on, I think it's the Visibility property of the checkbox that you should look for, I'll update the sample in a minute...

Comment: Now you are in the right track , then what should be the if condition which i should use to check/uncheck the control ??

Answer (score 0):

> The check box should be shown only when the Timezone (selected combo box item) supports daylight saving time. Also check/uncheck the checkbox based on the last configuration when the UI control is rendered.

If I am understanding your scenario correctly, there are two things going on here.  In order to show/hide the checkbox, you will need to check to see if the selected timezone supports DST, and set its visibility then.  But in order to set it to checked/unchecked based on the previous configuration, you will need to be storing that somehow - more than likely in a database, but I'm not sure the actual scenario.

As an idea of how your code will look, it may look similar to this:

```
private void TimeZonesListBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TimeZoneInfo info = (TimeZoneInfo)timeZoneListBox.SelectedItem;
    dstCheckBox.Visible = info.SupportsDaylightSavingTime;
    dstCheckBox.Checked = GetPreviousConfiguration(info);
}

private bool GetPreviousConfiguration(TimeZoneInfo timezone)
{
     //Code to lookup previous config.
}
```

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.